# Stripe account verification in test mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I wants to connect account to the stripe in test mode.

In documentation I found possible solution:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts#country

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
  -u sk_test_51INaqBF1YHDH3IgbpgrXxQ1QPwlxlrK39ZZ05pnsPmrR0OxnPGiQgObfRgdbAFbr352BnH7UOqHHEdm3YAMTZs8z00lV3enuFk: \
  -d "country"="US" \
  -d "type"="custom" \
  -d "capabilities[card_payments][requested]"="true" \
  -d "capabilities[transfers][requested]"="true"
```

But all accounts which I created are restricted

https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/connect/accounts/overview - here the list of accounts

How can I activate account without inputing real information

Comment: You have to provide the identity verification described at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#identity-and-address-verification- either via the API or the hosted onboarding, e.g. enter the details of someone, born 01/01/1901, with an address like `address_full_match,London,UK` , etc.